# C# user settings not loading when using Settings.Default.Properties

Tags: c#, properties, settings

I'm trying to find an easy way to load settings (I have a lot of them). I'm trying to make the settings name the same as the control name so i can loop through a list and match the settings to the correct controls. Something like `textBoxData.Data1 = MyProject.Settings.Default.Data1;` works completely fine.

I'm trying to use the property collection but its only giving me the design time default values, not the values saved in the user.config file (its saving correctly).

```
        Dictionary<String, String> settings_dictionary = new Dictionary<String, String>();
        foreach (SettingsProperty property in MyProject.Settings.Default.Properties)
        {

            try
            {
                String name = Convert.ToString(property.Name);
                String value = Convert.ToString(property.DefaultValue);
                settings_dictionary.Add(name, value);
                Debug.WriteLine("Loading from settings: {0} - {1}", name, value);
            }
            catch
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString());
            }
        }
```

There must be something I'm missing that I couldn't find. Also will gladly change to a better method!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `Settings.Default.PropertyValues` not `Settings.Default.Properties`

```
foreach (SettingsPropertyValue property in Lab.Properties.Settings.Default.PropertyValues)
{

    try
    {
        String name = Convert.ToString(property.Name);
        String value = Convert.ToString(property.PropertyValue);
        Console.WriteLine("{0}:{1}", name, value);
        Debug.WriteLine("Loading from settings: {0} - {1}", name, value);
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: so it WAS something simple i've missed, Thanks! works fine with custom settingsprovider too